# Temp Table Versus Cursor

Tags: t-sql

Is it possible to avoid the cursor completely by taking advantage of temp tables in stored procedure?

SQL Server 2008 onwards

Comment: It is definitely possible. What exactly are you trying to do? That will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an in memory table, using '''WITH''' statement.  Try to make a declarative call, rather than looping with Cursors this way.

ie:

```
With A as(
Select t.col1
From Table1 t
)
, B as(
Select t.col2
From Table2 t
)

Select A.col1
UNION
Select B.col2
```

You can join A, B, to other tables too